# Print matched field separators in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Given the following record

```
01-01-2012 18:02 some data 01-11-2014 20:22 some other data 10-02-2014 14:00 more data still
```

I am trying to group date, time and data and print them on separate lines like so:

```
01-01-2012 18:02 some data
01-11-2014 20:22 some other data
10-02-2014 14:00 more data still
```

However, what I have so far:

```
echo '01-01-2012 18:02 some data 01-11-2014 20:22 some other data 10-02-2014 14:00 more data still' | awk -F '[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*' '{ for ( n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }
```

results in this:

```
 some data 
 some other data 
 more data still
```

The dates and times are missing. They are field separators, therefore they don't print.

How can I modify my awk script in order to print every field separator that matches the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnu awk:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+' '!NF{s=RT;next} {print s $0}' file
01-01-2012 18:02 some data
01-01-2012 18:02 some other data
01-01-2012 18:02 more data still
```

---

**EDIT:** Using non-gnu awk you can do:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+/, "\n&"); 
      gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]+/, "\n")} 1' file
01-01-2012 18:02 some data
01-11-2014 20:22 some other data
10-02-2014 14:00 more data still
```

Also using `grep -P` you can do:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+.+?(?=[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|$)' file
01-01-2012 18:02 some data
01-11-2014 20:22 some other data
10-02-2014 14:00 more data still
```

Comment: see my comment above: awk only

Comment: Thanks, this one won't break if the pattern `[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+` shows up in the data. I use ox X's free BSD awk (non-GNU).

Comment: Yes that's right. I have also tested it on BSD awk (on OSX).

Answer (score 1):

awk way

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/)$i="\n"$i}1' file
```

Comment: you forget to print the result by `1` or `print`

Comment: @matsjoyce how is it awkward ?

Comment: @matsjoyce yeah i noticed a second after posting the comment ha, having a nightmare today!

Comment: breaks if the pattern `[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+` appears in data

Answer (score 1):

by awk

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf ($i~/-..-/)?RS $i:FS $i}' infile
```

#### explanation

- `for loop`: read the element one by one, elements are splitted by whitespace.
- `printf` : print the element without return
- `printf ($i~/-..-/)?RS $i:FS $i` - can be expended to if-else statement:
  `if ($i~/-..-/) {print RS $i) else (print FS $i)`

Comment: breaks if the pattern `[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+` appears in data